# c++ loop writing a vector to another one

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I have a vector V of size n. I would like to rewrite this vector to another vector X in such way that the X's first element would be V's first element, then X's second element would be V's LAST element, then V's second element, then V's element before the last one etc.
Is there a smart loop that would do that? 
Thanks in advance!

For those, who got confused by the description, it's essentially asking for the generation of:

```
X = { V[0], V[n-1], V[1], V[n-2], V[2], .... }
```

Comment: Example output, please.

Comment: fill 1st, 3rd, 5th... then fill 2nd, 4th, 6th....

Comment: IT's not very clear what you're asking for here, please give us an example.

Comment: Is it a homework? Why giving up the fun of solving it to someone else? :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, readability etc. I would do something like:

```
// split vector (assumes size is even!)
for( i=0; i<(V.size()/2); i++){
   X.push_back(V[i*2]);
   Y.push_back(V[i*2+1]);
}
// copy reversed Y onto X
for( i=Y.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
   X.push_back(Y[i]);
```

I think you get the idea.

Comment: As far as I know, the division operator is /, not \. Unless this is a C++14 feature...

Answer (score 0):

After the question edit, it becomes clear that you can just do this (for a vector v)

```
// function to interleave ranges, you'll see the usage later
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator interleave(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
                        InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2,
                        OutputIterator result)
{
  while (first1 != last1 || first2 != last2) 
  {
    if (first1==last1) return std::copy(first2,last2,result);
    if (first2==last2) return std::copy(first1,last1,result);

    *result++ = *first1++;
    *result++ = *first2++;
  }
}

int main() // example
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    // fill v with elements
    std::vector<int> result; // this is not an "in place solution"

    interleave(v.begin(), v.end(), v.rbegin(), v.rend(), back_inserter(result));
    // result holds the answer - keep that or assign it back to v
}
```

and here's a [use case](http://ideone.com/DMVnlp)

Comment: there's only one input vector ("V")

Comment: X is the output. (previous comment had a typo, sorry)

Comment: yepp, that's the output. you transform V to X. if still confused, write it down on paper with arrows...

Comment: the question never mentions any element of X as an input. let me edit the question.

Comment: I think you only need a reverse iterator to solve the problem, but first I wanted to make sure you understand the Q ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath v.rbegin(), v.rend() is a reverse range no need for reverse iterator. Solution is OK.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main() {
// your code goes here
vector<int> vec;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    vec.push_back(i);

copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
cout<<endl;

vector<int> second;
int length = vec.size();
for(int j = 0; j < length/2; j++)
{
    second.push_back(vec[j]);
    second.push_back(vec[length - j - 1]);
}
if(length % 2 == 1)
    second.push_back(vec[length/2]);

copy(second.begin(), second.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

the outpus is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 9 1 8 2 7 3 6 4 5
```